# Synchronous delay of javascript or a setTimeout solution for command interpreter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a simple interpreter for kids, which allows them to run programs and control an object in a grid. The whole thing is working fine, so at the end I started to work on the "looks and feel". What I would like to do is to execute each command after a time delay (so that the movement is visible) and allow the screen to "repaint" after each step.

From how I understand setTimeout, this will not help me, as it runs assynchronous (I do not want to execute code further). I even tried a little work-around (e.g. running loop until global variable is true -> and setting the variable to true in setTimeout function. That did not do the trick either (setTimout function fired only after browser told me the script probably stopped working, although the timeout was just 500ms).

So I am stuck - many answers here say that setTimeout can do everything and no "sleep" is needed. But in my case, I do not know...

Here is what I have (greatly simplified):

```
<table id="city_table" class="city" style="width: 400px">
        <tr>
                <td id="cellX1Y3" align="center"></td>
                <td id="cellX2Y3" align="center"</td>
                <td id="cellX3Y3" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td id="cellX1Y2" align="center"></td>
                <td id="cellX2Y2" align="center"></td>
                <td id="cellX3Y2" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td id="cellX1Y1" align="center">X</td>
                <td id="cellX2Y1" align="center"></td>
                <td id="cellX3Y1" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

(Notice the "X", which is our object to move around the grid).

Let's say our "program" is a string of commands "up right up" -> so when executed, the X moves to coordinates X1Y2, X2Y2, X2Y3.
Once user runs the program a function processCommandString(str) is fired, which looks like this:

```
processCommandString(str) {
    var aProgram = [];
    aProgram = str.split(" ");

    for (iP = 0; iP < aProgram.length; iP++) {
        cmdReturn = executeElementaryCommand(aProgram[iP]);
        switch(cmdReturn) {
            case 0:
                //all is ok, increase counters, etc., proceed with next command
                break;
            case 1:
                //non critical error in program (meaning user program, not mine)
                break;
            case 2:
                //critical error -> throw exception and stop
                break;
            case 10:
                // [IF like statement] -> evaluate condition and proceed accordingly
                break;
            case 20:
                // [LOOP like statement] -> ...
                break;
            case 90:
                // custom command
                break;
        //Please note that cases 10, 20, and 90 may call the processCommandString recursively
        } //end switch
    } //end for
}
```

Then we have a function processElementaryCommand(cmd).

```
function executeElementaryCommand(cmd_param) {
    var rtrn;
    switch (cmd) {
        case eCMDs[0]:  //MOVE
            //some stuff
            rtrn = objectX.step();
            break;

        case eCMDs[1]:  //TURN
            rtrn = objectX.turn(direction);
            break;

        //case ...  (continues for all elementary commands that are in eCMDs array
        //objectX is an object that actually updates the position of the "X" in the grid:
        //What it does: (1) sets $("cellXaYb").innerHTML="" -> a, b are current (old) coordinates; (2) sets $("cellXcYd").innerHTML="X" -> c, d being new coordinates

        default:
            //check here for custom commands
            rtrn = 99;
            break;
    }   //switch end
    return rtrn;
}
```

Now I would like to have the pause somewhere... Anywhere :) It can be in the objectX code, it can be in processElementaryCommand, or in processCommandString. But any solution I tried lead either to endless loop, or the table not being updated as the program proceeds (it was only updated once the X was on X2Y3 position).

Comment: The correct answer is still `setTimeout()`.

Comment: If you need to block a thread out of curiosity try this `var pauseTimeout = 1500; var startDate = new Date(); while (new Date() -  startDate < pauseTimeout) { }`, don't use it in production, change logic of your app to be async and use setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Pointy, setTimeout is still your answer. I can suggest a small guideline to your approach. You should consider having a current state object which stores the current state of the command as in what has been processed and what remains to be. This can be a global. Then you need to alter your functions in such a way that once a UI action is taken, the state object should be updated and the subsequent part of the processing should be done in another callable function that will be the argument to the setTimeout function.
It is important to note that this argument function perform only one more UI update and then again call setTimeout with the further processing function.

Comment: @Pointy - I admit your answer is correct, but as such it did not provide any help. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Igor Malyk -> I already tried that. The problem with that solution is that while the pause works and is taking place, the UI never gets updated. So you end up seeing the "X" in the final position only.

Comment: -> Thank you for your leads. I am not a programmer and this is my first program in javascript, so bear with me. I had to read your answer about 20 times, but finally I got it :)  I have created a jsfiddle for testing (only commands UP, RIGHT work and there is a hardcoded LOOP command to simulate loop code block). So original code (without delays) is here [Fiddle][1]  An updated fiddle with delays is here [Fiddle][2]   _Don't mind the effectiveness as I need the concept I will optimize later_   [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/BrandonSk/2cLghb2j/1/  [2]: https://jsfiddle.net/BrandonSk/fxd2kmzd/

Comment: **However** the code with delays works only for basic commands UP and RIGHT. The simulated block of commands (e.g. in a loop) does not work. I am currently working on the solution, but I'd like to ask for hints, how to tackle recursion. Create new and new objects (but then they will run parallel, which I do not want), or somehow save a state of current object and run subroutine in it? Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonSk, please refer the fiddle at [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sujitkm/ygspdcys/). I have made the LOOP also work. So , a command like "RIGHT LOOP RIGHT" etc will work. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you! This is a nice demonstration of difference between amateur and a pro :) I started working on a rather complex "current state" object, which had arrays as properties to do recursion. A lot of code and rather messy. Now look at your brilliant solution of around 10 lines achieving the same :) Thanks again. I still need to rewrite my former code, but I am sure it will work now. One last question: In the "exec" method you have this line "this.parent && this.parent.update();". While I know what it will do, I do not quite understand how it works. Could you explain please?

Comment: That is same as `if(this.parent) this.parent.update();`

Comment: Basically the execution thread comes here when a sequence of commands are processed. Consider if the command were RIGHT LOOP RIGHT, and when it had entered the `runSubRoutine()` and  after executing the last UP (3rd UP), you want to again start `update()` on the command after LOOP. This needs that the parent object's `update()` should get called. The state of the parent is currently pointing to the last RIGHT (of the original command after executing LOOP). Which allows the parent to continue processing from there.

Comment: The `this.parent &&` prevents the `parent.update()` to get called where there is no parent as in the case of the base command sequence.